# Type switch to []map[string]interface{} on the value of map[string]interface{}

Tags: json, go

## Problem

I'm facing the issue to remove not required arrays from an json object eg. arrays with only one element which is not an object or array. (No arrays as root of the input)

### Example

In:

```
{"name": [{ "inner": ["test"] }]}
```

Wanted Out:

```
{"name": [{ "inner": "test" }]}
```

### Approach

I started with a simple type switch on the values of a parsed `map[string]interface{}` and recognized that it wont switch to the case `[]map[string]interface{}`. (Given example)

So here is the implementation I came up with. It works for most of the scenarios but not for inner Objects within an array yet.

```golang
type jsonMap map[string]interface{}
type jsonMapList []map[string]interface{}

m := jsonMap{}

err := json.Unmarshal(s, &m)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

res := removeFromObject(m)

bytes, err := json.Marshal(res)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
result := string(bytes)
log.Infof("Parse Result: %s", result)

func removeFromObject(in jsonMap) jsonMap {
    res := jsonMap{}

    for k, v := range in {
        switch value := v.(type) {
        case jsonMap:
            res[k] = removeFromObject(value)
        case jsonMapList:
            list := []jsonMap{}
            for _, entry := range value {
                list = append(list, removeFromObject(entry))
            }
            res[k] = list
        case []interface{}:
            if len(value) == 1 {
                res[k] = value[0]
            } else {
                res[k] = value
            }
        default:
            res[k] = value
        }
    }

    return res
}
```

### Question

How do I switch case to an object array, so that I can recursively resolve the objects within that array too?

Comment: This https://play.golang.com/p/mwo7Y2rJ_lc works for the example case, not sure if it works for every case you expect.

Comment: ... also note that an array of objects unmarshaled into an `interface{}` will have the underlying type set to `[]interface{}` and never to `[]map[string]interface{}` as you seem to assume.

Comment: Maybe you can use Regex. Find array with one element and remove the square brackets.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you for that snipped. I works as expected my various test cases. Please provide it as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to remove the undesired arrays.

```
func removearr(x interface{}) interface{} {
    switch val := x.(type) {
    case map[string]interface{}:
        for k, v := range val {
            val[k] = removearr(v)
        }
        return val
    case []interface{}:
        if len(val) == 1 {
            // remove array only if the value is not an object
            if _, ok := val[0].(map[string]interface{}); !ok {
                return removearr(val[0])
            }
        }

        for i, v := range val {
            val[i] = removearr(v)
        }
        return val
    default:
        return x
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/mwo7Y2rJ_lc